# Is new stack frame allocated for the block(conditional or unconditional) code in c/c++?

Tags: c++, function, memory-management, stack, callstack

I looked at posts which differentiate between stack and heap allocations.
I understand that stack frame is allocated for each function calls.

But my question lies around the blocks inside the functions? How is memory managed/allocated for such code?
How is the local storage size for such a stack frame created?

```
class A; class B; class C;

func block() {
    if (condition) {
        A var;
    } else {
        B var;
    }

    {
        A var;
        B var;
        C var;
    }

}
```

Comment: One way to find out: https://godbolt.org/z/SgU-Uw. As you can see even without optimization the memory for this variables isn't allocated because the variables aren't used (or because the classes are empty).

Comment: In general, the classes won't be empty, would have some amount of data.
There is no mention of this is any of the Q/A.

Basically of these kind of conditions?

Also will have some manipulations and function calls on the variables in the blocks.

Comment: I think this is a technical implementation detail. AFAIK the terms heap and stack aren't even mentioned in the standard in this context.

Comment: Basically this - https://godbolt.org/z/YvQG5r  .. Ohh.. so is compiler dependent?

Comment: If the classes are small enough, the compiler may just decide to shove everything in CPU registers. And because the function doesn't call other functions, it might be possible to skip its stack frame altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note this is a pure implementation detail, the compiler is free to do what it will so long as the result behaves as-if the original code were executed. Stack frames are simply a detail real hardware use to get there.

That said, most real-world compilers will simply calculate all the stack space a given function might need and allocate that on function entry. It won't necessarily all be used (a particular block might not even be entered on a given function call, as an example) but the stack space for the variables that block requires will still have been reserved as part of the function prologue. This is done rather than mess with changing the stack space at several points in a function execution.